# How do you make an Ubuntu server with docker?

Tags: ubuntu, docker

is there any way to make an Ubuntu system accessible to all devices connected to my network, maybe by using ssh or anything else. I'm trying to run it in docker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to get a bash shell in the Ubuntu container from another machine? Here's one way to do this:

In the host machine, give the remote user permission to execute docker commands.

```
sudo usermod -aG docker USERNAME
```

The remote user can SSH into the host machine

```
ssh USERNAME@HOST
```

and use `docker exec` command to get a terminal of the container. (Note that the container should be running when using this command.)

```
docker exec -it CONTAINER_ID /bin/bash
```

If you meant to get a service running on a port of the ubuntu container from another machine, let me know. I'll update my answer.

Comment: sorry for the late answer, but is there any way to run it in windows?

Comment: and i meant to ssh into the container, not the host

Comment: Sorry for being late. Unfortunately, I don't know about this in windows. I googled a bit about directly sshing into a container. I couldn't find any easy solution. This procedure - sshing into docker host and then `docker exec` - will have the same outcome as sshing into containers.